# Using Openargs to set a default value for a field

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to create a menu where you select some dropdowns, and then click and it populates default values based on your selections.  Here is my code, which I've verified passes the correct value to strValue2, but when the form opens my INPUT_BY displays #Name?

```
Private Sub Form_Open(cancel As Integer)

    Dim intPos As Integer
    Dim strValue1 As String
    Dim strValue2 As String
    Dim oLen As Long
    Dim oRght As Long
    
    oLen = Len(Me.OpenArgs)
    
    If oLen > 0 Then
        ' Position of the pipe
        intPos = InStr(Me.OpenArgs, "|")
        oRght = oLen - intPos
        End If
                    
    If intPos > 0 Then
        'Retrieve Value1 from the first part of the string
        strValue1 = Split(Me.OpenArgs, "|")(0)
        'Retrieve Value2 to Assign from the end of the string
        strValue2 = Split(Me.OpenArgs, "|")(1)

    End If
          
     'Debug
    'MsgBox strValue2
  
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
    Me.INPUT_BY.DefaultValue = strValue2
    Me.ACFT.SetFocus
        
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured this one out - I needed to add text delimiters around strValue2

```
Private Sub Form_Open(cancel As Integer)

    Dim intPos As Integer
    Dim strValue1 As String
    Dim strValue2 As String
    Dim oLen As Long
    Dim oRght As Long
    
    oLen = Len(Me.OpenArgs)
    
    If oLen > 0 Then
        ' Position of the pipe
        intPos = InStr(Me.OpenArgs, "|")
        oRght = oLen - intPos
        End If
                    
    If intPos > 0 Then
        'Retrieve Value1 from the first part of the string
        strValue1 = Split(Me.OpenArgs, "|")(0)
        'Retrieve Value2 to Assign from the end of the string
        strValue2 = Split(Me.OpenArgs, "|")(1)

    End If
          
     'Debug
    'MsgBox strValue2
  
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
    Me.INPUT_BY.DefaultValue = """" & strValue2 & """"
    Me.ACFT.SetFocus
```